# Simplifying a linear algebra derivation involving the determinant lemma

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

Starting with the matrix determinant lemma
$$
\mathrm{det}(\mathbf{AB}^{\top} + \mathbf{X}) = \mathrm{det}(\mathbf{X})\mathrm{det}(\mathbf{B}^{\top} \mathbf{X}^{-1}\mathbf{A} + \mathbf{I}_n)
$$
where $\mathbf{A, B}$ are of size $m\times n$, and the special case in which $\mathbf{X} = \mathbf{I}_m$ where
$$
\mathrm{det}(\mathbf{AB}^{\top} + \mathbf{I}_m) = \mathrm{det}(\mathbf{B}^{\top}\mathbf{A} + \mathbf{I}_n)
$$
Consider
$$
\mathrm{det}(\mathbf{GAG}^{\top} + \mathbf{B})
$$
Where $\mathbf{A}$ is $n\times n$, $\mathbf{B}$ is $m\times m$ and $\mathbf{G}$ is $m\times n$. If we assume that $\mathbf{A}$ permits an arbitrary factorisation into the product of two square matrices such that $\mathbf{A = XY}$, then we may write
$$
\mathrm{det}(\mathbf{GAG}^{\top} + \mathbf{B}) = \mathrm{det}(\mathbf{(GX)(YG^{\top})} + \mathbf{B}) = \mathrm{det}(\mathbf{B}) \, \mathrm{det}(\mathbf{(YG^{\top})}\mathbf{B}^{-1}\mathbf{(GX)} + \mathbf{I}_n)
$$
Now let $\mathbf{H} = \mathbf{G^{\top} B}^{-1}\mathbf{G}$. If we additionally assume that $\mathbf{H}$ permits some factorisation into two $n \times n$ matrices such that $\mathbf{H = LU}$ we may write
$$
\mathrm{det}(\mathbf{YHX} + \mathbf{I}_n) = \mathrm{det}(\mathbf{(YL)(UX)} + \mathbf{I}_n) = \mathrm{det}(\mathbf{(UX)(YL)} + \mathbf{I}_n) = \mathrm{det}(\mathbf{UAL} + \mathbf{I}_n).
$$
This yields the desired result that
$$
\mathrm{det}(\mathbf{GAG}^{\top} + \mathbf{B}) = \mathrm{det}(\mathbf{B}) \,\mathrm{det}(\mathbf{UAL} + \mathbf{I}_n).
$$

**My question:**

Given that the factorisation $\mathbf{A = XY}$ we assumed in the derivation doesn't appear in the final result, and the fact that the determinant lemma was used twice, I feel like I might have arrived there in a slightly clunky way. Can anyone see an alternative route to the result where we do not need to assume the factorisation of $\mathbf{A}$?

Thanks!

Comment: $\mathbf{YG}$ is an $m \times n$ matrix by the definition. Since $\mathbf{G}$ is also an $m \times n$ matrix, $\mathbf{Y}$ is a $... \times m$ matrix, which is impossible as $\mathbf{A}=\mathbf{XY}$ is an $n \times n$ matrix. I think the argument collapses from here.

Comment: @TheSimpliFire Ah there's an error in my typing out - there are transpose operators on the outside of parenthesis that shouldn't be, i.e. $(\mathrm{YG})^{\top}$ instead of $(\mathrm{YG}^{\top})$ - I've made the appropriate edits, so hopefully the argument is now sound. Thanks!